# How to Build/Run Visual C++ code with events?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, events, visual-c++

I implemented native C++ events [as given example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/event-handling-in-native-cpp?view=msvc-160) but as it says there, the program needs to be compiled in a specific way (cl /EHsc /W3 evh_native.cpp), so how can I add that to Visual Studio compiler? The main problem is that Visual Studio compiler doesn't recognize `[event_source(native)]` or `[event_receiver(native)]` part.

Comment: What is the compiler flag `/permissive-` set to ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Well there is a bunch of stuff written there, should I post that in update on post? Or should I add cl /EHsc /W3 to that?

Comment: @RichardCritten My mistake, there is already /EHsc and /W3 there

Comment: @RichardCritten I actually disable permissive mode (Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Language->Conformance Mode (No)) and It compiled, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RichardCritten , I solved the issue.  I disabled permissive mode (Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Language->Conformance Mode (No)) and It compiled.